# How to sort through a full folder of files and returning the names of the files that add up to x

Tags: linux, shell, unix

As the title says I have been given a directory full of 1000 text files containing only 5 numbers 1000 or less. I need to then find which files list of numbers add up to 2000

Now almost all of my programming knowledge is C++, Java, Javascript so I am very new to all this. This is the first class and list of exercises, all of the previous ones are basic one line in the command line so I feel like I have done this the wrong way and I was wondering if there is a better more simple way.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000}
do

if (($i < 10));
    then
    perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { $int = $sum' 0000$i
elif (($i < 100));
    then
    perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { $int = $sum' 000$i
elif (($i < 1000));
    then
    perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { $int = $sum' 00$i
else
    perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { $int = $sum' 0$i

fi

if [[ $int -eq 2718 ]]
    then
    if (($i < 10));
        then
        echo 0000$i
    elif (($i < 100));
        then
        echo 000$i
    elif (($i < 1000));
        then
        echo 00$i
    else 
        echo 0$i
    fi
fi
done
```

P.S This isn't an assignment, it's practice

Comment: your `i` has a max value of `10`, so those `i<100` and 'i<1000' checks will always be true

Comment: Why start a whole bunch of Perl processes - you could do the whole thing in Perl or awk.

Comment: Are you supposed to use bash-only? If not, ditto the `perl` or `awk`. Let us know.

Comment: The previous question is to find which files contain the number 999. This is obviously really simple just using grep. I'm wondering if there is a simple way similar to this. The above is the only thing i could think of.